# Vertical and horizontal lines for whole page

Tags: rules, cv, marginpar

I have a quick question regarding drawing lines. For practicing, I want to imitate the following CV:

[image]

For that I would like to ask for some directions when it comes to drawing vertical and horizontal lines, as well as positioning of the texts.

Comment: Could you, if possible, clip the picture a bit, so that it only shows the design in question? The large blue buttons are a bit distracting ... =)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to draw the lines directly underneath a line of text. You can use the following approach to draw a line exactly through the position where you place the macros (horizontally at the baseline of the text):

As an example, the green dashed line divides the word "vertical" exactly between the t and the i. The lines can even be styled if needed. You need to compile twice to get the positions right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{linecount}

\newcommand{\horizontalline}[1][]{%
    \stepcounter{linecount}%
    \tikzmark{hlineanchor\thelinecount}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
        \draw[#1] ({current page.west} |- {pic cs:hlineanchor\thelinecount}) -- ({current page.east} |- {pic cs:hlineanchor\thelinecount});
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\verticalline}[1][]{%
    \stepcounter{linecount}%
    \tikzmark{vlineanchor\thelinecount}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
        \draw[#1] ({current page.north} -| {pic cs:hlineanchor\thelinecount}) -- ({current page.south} -| {pic cs:hlineanchor\thelinecount});
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Hello horizontal line! \horizontalline[blue]

\lipsum[1]

Hello the other horizontal line! \horizontalline[red]

\lipsum[1]

And then, there is a vert\verticalline[green!50!black, thick, dashed]ical line that divides the word `vertical' exactly in the middle!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Do you know of any other ways of doing it without tikz?

Comment: The nice thing about Ti*k*z is, that you can get a combination of absolute (page margin) and relative (position of current character on page) positions. Would other packages be okay?

Comment: I am open to other packages! I am just messing around on how to do it most efficiently so I am always up to learn new stuffs :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `tikz` (make sure to run twice):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, blue]
    ([yshift=-2in]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-2in]current page.north east);
     \draw[line width=1.5pt, green]
    ([xshift=-6in]current page.north east) -- ([xshift=-6in]current page.south east);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]